# Divide text in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, nodes

I want to write a small wysiwyg editor ( just text ). Currently, I am trying to apply the spans correctly. To surround the selected content, I use this code:

```
var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange(); // FF : IE
if(sel.getRangeAt){ // thats for FF
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("span"); 
    newNode.setAttribute('class', 'green');
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
} else { //and thats for IE7
    sel.pasteHTML('<span style="color:green">'+sel.htmlText+'</span>');
}
```

Note that this is not my code, I found it here on stackoverflow.

This works fine in this example: 
"I'm going home", so when I mark I'm and afterwords home, everything works fine and i get `<span class="green">I</span> go <span class="green">Home</span>`.

But now, when I select 'm till hom, i get this error

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

The reason is that the span would be set in the wrong place ( at least I think so ) 
So the right output would be: `<span class="green">I</span><span class="green">'m go hom</span><span class="green">e</span>`.

So how could i manage that the spans get set right/divide and set new at the right place withut any addintional plugins ?

If anything is unclear, just leave a comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/equalsound/2waoepm6/3/

Comment: could you please create a snippet to see it live?

Comment: I think you're looking for [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Comment: [link] https://jsfiddle.net/equalsound/2waoepm6/3/  

So when u mark "m" and "home" and them from "m" to "home", u get the error

Comment: not quite sure if markdown is realy the right thing ...